# Taxonomy terms follow/unfollow module

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there any module or options to allow site users to follow or unfollow the taxonomy terms?Basing on the following terms, I have to send a notification if any new post has been created on those particular terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this module will do the trick: [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions).

Comment: Awesome, I was just about to suggerst Rules but then I saw your answer

Answer (score 2):

[Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) or [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions) are the best options.

> This is a complete Subscriptions/Notifications Framework aiming at extendability and scalability. It allows any number of plug-ins defining new event types or subscription types or a different user interface.

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions. Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions.